# JS script - Value Dependent (multiple dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Right now I have two dropdowns and the goal is to have the User select "OFF" on the first option, the second dropdown automatically selects "ON" and vice versa.

The code currently below with the JavaScript works, but works for only one pair of the dropdown. I was wondering what I need to change to make it work for both pairs or even four pairs in the future.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
     <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">OFF</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">ON</option>
     </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
     <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
      <option value=" "  selected="selected">Select Option</option>
      <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
      <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
     </select>
    </div> 
    

    <br>
    
    <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
     <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">OFF</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">ON</option>
     </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
     <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
      <option value=" "  selected="selected">Select Option</option>
      <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
      <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
     </select>
    </div> 
   </form>
  </div>
    <script>
const cmicrophone = document.querySelectorAll('.select1')[0];
const microphone = document.querySelectorAll('.select2')[0];
function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
 otherSelect.selectedIndex =thisSelect.selectedIndex
        }
        cmicrophone.addEventListener('change', event => {
    inputHandler(cmicrophone, microphone);
  });

  microphone.addEventListener('change', event => {
    inputHandler(microphone, cmicrophone);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
     <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">OFF</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">ON</option>
     </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
     <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
      <option value=" "  selected="selected">Select Option</option>
      <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
      <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
     </select>
    </div> 
    

    <br>
    
    <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
     <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">OFF</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">ON</option>
     </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
     <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
      <option value=" "  selected="selected">Select Option</option>
      <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
      <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
     </select>
    </div> 
   </form>
  </div>
    <script>
var cmicrophone = document.querySelectorAll('.select1');
var microphone = document.querySelectorAll('.select2');
 
function inputHandlerCmicrophone(thisSelect, otherSelect, j) {
    
    var test = document.querySelectorAll('.select1');
    for(i=0; i<test.length; i++){
        if(test[i] == j){
            otherSelect[i].selectedIndex =thisSelect[i].selectedIndex
            break;
}
}

 
        }
   function inputHandlerMicrophone(thisSelect, otherSelect, j) {

    var test = document.querySelectorAll('.select2');
    for(i=0; i<test.length; i++){
        if(test[i] == j){
            otherSelect[i].selectedIndex =thisSelect[i].selectedIndex
            break;
}

 
        }}
        for(i=0; i<cmicrophone.length; i++) {
            cmicrophone[i].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    inputHandlerCmicrophone(cmicrophone, microphone, e.target);
  });
}
        
        for(k=0; k<microphone.length; k++) {
            microphone[k].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    inputHandlerMicrophone(microphone, cmicrophone, e.target);
  });
}
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want all of them to be linked together though.

Comment: Please explain what you want clearly. So i can help you. Cheers

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Right now your code affects both pairs of dropdown. I need them to be independent because I'll have 4 pairs of dropdown eventually. I can't have all of them link together. They all should have the same functionality, if one pick YES then the other is NO and vice versa, but it can't be linked like it is right now sir

Comment: I will. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using document.getElementById() instead of querySelectorAll().  The problem is that you're always accessing the first one, element 0.  You also need to ensure you have unique values for each 'id' property; in the code above you have duplicate values for microphone and cmicrophone.

You will need to add a loop for dynamic number of selects by fetching all of them and iterating over them to map each of the event handlers:

```
const cmicrophones = document.querySelectorAll('.select1');
const microphones = document.querySelectorAll('.select2');
for (var i = 0; i < cmicrophones.length; i++) {
  const cmicrophone = cmicrophones[i];
  const microphone = microphones[i];

  ....
}
```

Comment: I did provide an example in my answer; what part do you not understand?

Comment: so if the id is different say "microphone1" and "cmicrophone1" I would just continue in the for loop.... "const cmicrophone1 = cmicrophone1[i];.....??

Comment: In the example I provided, I'm not using IDs.  I was suggesting the use of IDs because it is much faster to look up by ID than by querySelector

Comment: So if I'm wrong please let me know. You're calling select all on the select1 and 2 which will be the variable. The for loop is then? I don't get .